# How to make Vue import files from assets folder instead of hardcoded script tags inside of index.html

Tags: javascript, vue.js, import, cdn, vue-cli

I have a very simple structure and want to import assets that come from cdnjs.com.

Basically, those assets required for some third-party libraries, but the issue is it doesn't want to import them when I download and put all of the files inside of src/assets/lib and import them like

main.js:

```
import './assets/lib/jquery.min.js'
```

My application stops working and says that jQuery is not defined, but when I import them inside of index.html everything is fine:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.3.0/raphael.min.js"></script>
```

Detailed stack of error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at eval (amalia.js.min.js?c1e6:27)
    at Object../src/assets/amalia/build/js/amalia.js.min.js (app.js:1362)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:849)
    at fn (app.js:151)
    at eval (cjs.js?!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js?!./src/components/Videoplayer/AmaliaPlayer.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&:2)
    at Module../node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js?!./src/components/Videoplayer/AmaliaPlayer.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& (app.js:1010)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:849)
    at fn (app.js:151)
    at eval (AmaliaPlayer.vue?6fc3:1)
    at Module../src/components/Videoplayer/AmaliaPlayer.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& (app.js:1688)
```

I need those assets located in src/assets folder because I want to build an SFC for further import in my projects

I also tried to set window.jQuery but seems like it's not the best approach so really want your help guys :)

Comment: Did you try npm install jquery? And then import $ from "jquery" ?

Comment: $ exists on the window object, but I need window.jQuery

Comment: Why do you want it on window,if you can use the imports? Is it something legacy?

Answer (score 0):

After 2 hours of fighting I found the solution:

npm i jquery --save

// *vue.config.js*

```
const webpack = require('webpack')
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    plugins: [
      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: 'jquery',
        jquery: 'jquery',
        'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
        jQuery: 'jquery'
      })
    ]
  },
}
```